# Docker projects containers nginx conf referencing totally different project. Running on mac (This is really weird!)

Tags: docker, nginx, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

I'm using mac mojave on a 2012 macbook pro.

I have the latest docker desktop running, latest postgres and latest vscode. I've actually re-installed them and tried to sort out the issue I'm facing.

This issue is weird. Where do I start!!!
I'm trying to use a repo's configuration found on github to get nginx running in a multi container application using reverse proxy.

I have also some other docker projects I've been developing on mac built with docker-compose
same as the repo found here
https://github.com/115design/nuxt-django-postgresql

Now this is where it gets strange.
If I prune, Containers, networks, images and volumes and do a fresh clone of the project on github the nginx logs are referencing a host from a totally different project.

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "asgiserver:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13
2020/11/13 23:13:47 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "asgiserver:8000" in 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:13
```

So now what I've done is deleted and reinstalled, Docker and vs code.
and I'm still getting reference to this upstream config from a totally different project.

I actually cloned the repo I'm copying on github on ec2 just for my own sanity and the logs from nginx are different when the projects up. No reference to **asgiserver**

How on earth is another projects config showing up in a different projects container?

Comment: This is really a question for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). That being said, you haven't defined an upstream. Try opening a shell in that container to inspect the config. This is highly unlikely to be a VS Code or Docker problem. This is an Nginx configuration problem, plain and simple.

Comment: Where did line 13 of `nginx.conf` come from? It didn't arrive there by magic. My guess is your `Dockerfile` either copies the wrong thing in, or when you launch your container you're mounting a volume from the wrong project.

Comment: @tadman This is a fresh pull from a repo on github. I've done this in different directories a few times. I can't open a shell because the container keeps restarting. restart always is true in the docker-compose config. The error keeps crashing the container. All volumes are pruned and containers etc multiple times.

Comment: You can always launch it with a `CMD` override. `docker run -it --rm CONTAINER bash` usually does it, though if you have other options for environment or volumes (`-v`) be sure to include those as well. You could also override that in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @tadman docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: You may need to find out what shell is available if `bash` doesn't exist. `sh` is sometimes the only thing that works.

Comment: I tried that and the same error.

Comment: I can't really debug this via comments. You'll need to find out what shell(s) are available and pop one open. The container documentation may offer hints.

Comment: @tadman I'm going to try rebuild project force recreate and remove orphans. Maybe that will help. I suspect this is some cache issue with docker containers being re-used and not being properly pruned. I've also renamed the nginx container. Lets see what happens

Comment: You can always dump all your docker images and do a scratch build that way, but in my experience that's only a solution for low disk space, not issues like this.

Comment: @tadman I've low enough disk space. what's the command for doing that? Well 13 gb free

Comment: [`docker image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Comment: @tadman I tried that before posting question. I thought there was another command for force dumping the images. What's weird is I can't get rid of the images in vscode. Even though I delete them from the interface and prune with docker image prune they still show

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving the issue. I was using docker plugin for vs code.
Somehow in the images section a list of old images were present. Docker image prune would not remove these so manually deleting them was the only way. After deletion app worked as intended.